# Xamarin.Forms: Disable auto create strong password on login page

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

We have a login page where users type in a PIN code that we have emailed to them.

The Xamarin.Forms app uses `<Entry IsPassword="True" />` so we get the nice *******d functionality when typing.

BUT when users try to log in on iPhones it suggests a "strong password" for this field. It is as if the phone thinks the user is creating a password.  (See image.)  This results in a ton of confusion and a sub-optimal user experience.

How can this autosuggestion/autofill be disabled?  What have we overlooked :-)

[Iphone created a strong password for this app... when logging in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSiOs.png)

- We do not see this in the emulators.
- And we know that users can disable autofill in the phone settings, but users shouldn't do that.
- Changing the IsPassword to false solves the issue but then the password is visible.
- We also see that deleting the email Entry before the password solves the issue... but we need the email.

Thanks /Per

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From iOS 12, you might have seen iOS suggesting strong password while signing up for an app. This is a new feature in iOS .

If you do want to disable it , you could use **Custom Renderer**

#### in Forms

create a custom Entry

```
namespace xxx
{
    public  class MyEntry:Entry
    {

    }
}
```

#### in iOS

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using xxx.iOS;
using xxx;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                Control.TextContentType = UITextContentType.Password;

                // set it as NewPassword will appear the issue
                //Control.TextContentType = UITextContentType.NewPassword;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great Lucas, that did solve the issue.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Not working at all, but find Control.SecureTextEntry is the key.

Answer (score -1):

Set `Control.SecureTextEntry` as `false` will fix the problem.

in iOS

```
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using xxx.iOS;
using xxx;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyEntry), typeof(MyEntryRenderer))]
namespace xxx.iOS
{
    public class MyEntryRenderer: EntryRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control != null)
            {
                // To disable the "Use Strong Password" given by iOS
                Control.SecureTextEntry = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```